# How to prevent onchange event triggering on page load javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get value on change event, it is working fine but the only issue it is triggering also on page load.

```html
<select id="test" name="age" onchange="sendValue()">
  <option value="yes">Test1</option>
  <option value="no">Test2</option>
</select>
```

```js
function sendValue() {
  var test1 = document.getElementById("test").value;

  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {}
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "btnCompas.php?q=" + test1, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

How can I prevent this happening on page load? Thanks in adavance.

Comment: May be you are invoking the function somewhere in your JavaScript.

Comment: Agreed @Saral. Else what you can do instead of using  `onchange` in HTML call it from Javascript instead `document.getElementById("test").onchange = function() {  sendValue()};`.

Comment: Make sure that the same function is not triggered by the onload event. May be any third party code conflicting with this. If so, try changing the name of this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the event listener in the window's load handler:

```html
<html>
<body>
<select id="test" name="age">
  <option value="yes">Test1</option>
  <option value="no">Test2</option>
</select>
</body>
<script>
function sendValue() {
  console.log("(!)");
}

window.addEventListener(
  'load', 
  () => {
    const select = document.querySelector('#test');
    select.addEventListener('change', sendValue);
  });
</script>
</html>
```

This guarantees that `sendValue` won't be called before page load.

---

**NOTE:**

You can also use the `DOMContentLoaded` event on `document` instead of `Window.load`. The difference is that `DOMContentLoaded` will fire once the HTML in your page was loaded and parsed. `Window.load` will wait for page resources to load.